# get value from correct input field

Tags: jquery

I have a html structure likes this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and a on change function:

```
$( ".inputForSum" ).change(function() {
   console.log(  $('.inputForSum').val()  )
});
```

But I need to know, WHICH input field with the class "inputForm" has changed.
How can I realize this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( ".inputForSum" ).change(function() {
   console.log(  $(this).val()  )
   console.log($(this).closest('tr'))
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can use $(this) to get the input that changed

it s `$(this).val()`

Comment: okay thank you ! but my explanation was wrong. I need to now, which <tr> element is the parent of the changed inputForSum value. because in this tr tags are other  input values, which I need to change with my on change function

Comment: u can use $(this).closest('tr')

Answer (score 1):

Is the index of the `tr` parent an acceptable answer ?

```js
$( ".inputForSum" ).change(function(ev) {
   console.log($(ev.target).closest("tr").index(), $(ev.target).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="text-center inputForSum" type="text" name="menge" value="1.00" />
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```